Can't modify Info.plist (Operation not permitted)
% sudo cp /tmp/Info.plist .
Password:
cp: ./Info.plist: Operation not permitted

% pwd
/Applications/Xcode-15.4.app/Contents

% ls -@ledO . Info.plist 
drwxr-xr-x  18 antontropashko  staff  -   576 Nov 15 14:26 .
-rw-r--r--@  1 antontropashko  staff  - 32436 Nov 15 14:26 Info.plist
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16 
    com.apple.macl     72 
    com.apple.xcode.PlistType      53 

How can I fix this?

Caveat: original Info.plist has to be preserved somewhere to be restored later, rest you want to turn that Xcode (or whatever is that you are trying to resuscitate on Sequoia) copy into a doorstop.
The file has an extended attribute indicating the existence of an ACL, but no actual ACL. To clean up, you can do either of the following

Run sudo xattr -d com.apple.macl Info.plist to remove the extended attribute
Overwrite the file with cat /tmp/Info.plist > Info.plist

Then if that was to exhumate Xcode do the
xcodeselect/license dance described here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78996419/xcode-15-is-not-running-in-macos-sequoia/79098243?noredirect=1#comment139664069_79098243
cause in UI you' get stuck at the license acceptance prompt

The question is about updating Info.plist. Not sure what the reference to Xcode in the answer helps.
